# Autowired field null when overriden method is invoked

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am trying to get basic authentication added to my webservice calls, with the following bean -

```
@Component
public class WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth extends HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender {

    @Autowired
    ConfigProperties config;

    @Value("${password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    public void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws    IOException {
         System.out.println("properties : "+config + "password "+password);
    } 
}
```

When I invoke a webservice call via webtemplate (Soap handler), above fields are resolved as null (have got this working using hardcoded values till now)
However, if I invoke the above method from my SpringBoot app's main method, the properties are resolved correctly -

WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth ww = ctx.getBean(WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth.class);
ww.prepareConnection(null);

produces correct output.

What is the root cause of this ?

Comment: please post the code for "call via webtemplate". Most likely webtemplate is creating new instance of WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth and therefore fields are initialized to null

Comment: Ah, I missed Autowiring the WebServiceMessageSenderWithAuth class in my webtemplate. I was creating a new instance instead, hence the autowiring didn't kick-in. Thanks for your foresight :)